# Отсутствует обязательный для компилятора член

Tags: c#, .net, com

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: В части кода после процесса сборки появляется ошибка:

> "Ошибка    CS0656  Отсутствует обязательный для компилятора член "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.Convert"

Указывал директиву `Microsoft.CSharp` в классе - безрезультатно.

В документации microsoft нашел описание ошибки:

> Отсутствует обязательный для компилятора член "объект.член"
>   
> Существует одна из следующих проблем:
>   
> - Установка среды CLR повреждена.
>   
> - Имеется ссылка на сборку, определяющая тип, который также находится в среде CLR. Однако тип сборки не определяет путь, который ожидает компилятор C#.
>   
> Проверьте ссылки, чтобы убедиться, что используется правильная версия среды CLR.

Ссылку добавлял через Менеджер ссылок -> Com - > Windows Script Host Object Model

Причина скорее всего во втором варианте, но я же по сути ничего извне не добавлял

Answer (score 5):

Как сказано [вот в этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24321962/4340086), все дело в том, что новая студия для COM-ссылок генерирует интерфейсы, которые используют dynamic. А dynamic не поддерживается в старых фреймворках (2.0-3.5).

Соответственно, вам поможет одно из следующих решений:

1. перейти на .NET Framework 4.0;
2. как подсказали [вот в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24359907/4340086), можно выключить настройку "Embed interop types" (в русской версии должно быть что-то про встраивание или внедрение) для ссылки на COM-библиотеку - это отключит новый механизм импорта;
3. можно сгенерировать управляемую библиотеку при помощи утилиты tlbimp и сослаться на нее в проекте;
4. наконец, можно самостоятельно написать интерфейсы и классы, которые обычно студия генерирует за вас.

Comment: Спасибо, помог вариант 2